# Remove row if row contains X in any of the cells

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel worksheet there are 3 columns where there might be "X". Those columns are A,F,G. I want to delete the entire row, if "X" is in any of these columns.

I have tried looking up many other forums, posts, etc. But I couldn't change the code I found to suit my needs. I am new to Visual Basic.

I have found this code

```
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lRow = 390
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, 5).Value = "none" Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

From what I understand, this code goes all the way from 390th row to the first one. The problem is I don't know how many rows I'll have. Also it looks for the value "none" in the fifth column. I have 3 columns in which the value might appear (A,F,G)

The output should be rows that don't contain X in any of those 3 mentioned columns.

Comment: Are you sure you are using VB.Net (in Visual Studio)? I suspect you are using VBA (in Excel).

Comment: FYI - Say your column "A" will have the most data, to get the last row do `lRow = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row`

Comment: Yes I am using VBA in Excel

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you could do this:

```
Dim lRow As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
Dim findStr as String
findStr = "X"
lRow = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(iCntr, 1).Value = findStr or Cells(iCntr, 6).Value = findStr or Cells(iCntr, 7).Value = findStr Then
        Rows(iCntr).Delete
    End If
Next iCntr
```

There are more efficient ways I'm sure but this should get you started.

Comment: By looking this is really it! But unfortunately I dont know why, but I get Run-time error 13 type mismatch. Do you know why that happens? As I said I am new to this

Comment: @Peter oh, you may need `Rows(iCntr).EntireRow.Delete`